# Algorithm for the transitive reduction of a DAG

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

I'm looking for an algorithm for the transitive reduction of a digraph (a DAG in fact).

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction#Graph_algorithms_for_transitive_reduction) displays a formula $R^-$ = $R - (R \times R^+)$ — where $R^-$ is the transitive reduction of $R$ and $R^+$ is the transitive closure of $R$ — but that Cartesian product doesn't form an edge (unless I'm missing something), so how can I take away from $R$?

For example, say $3$ depends on $2$ and $1$, and $2$ depends on $1$.  The edges of this graph $G$ are $(2, 1)$, $(3, 1)$, and $(3, 2)$.

I'm expecting the reduction to be $G' = \{(2, 1), (3, 2)\}$.
The transitive closure of $G$ is $G$, right?

Comment: The product $\times$ is composition, i.e. $x (R \times R^+) y$ iff there is $z$ such that $x R z$ and $z R^+ y$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, you can add your response as an answer to get best answer.

Answer (score 0):

The product $\times$ is composition, i.e. $x(R \times R^+)y$ iff there is $z$ such that $xRz$ and $zR^+y$.

---

*Added Yuval Filmus's comment as a CW answer to mark this question as answered.*